# My google apps gmail does not receive emails from hotmail

Tags: email, dns, google-apps, spf, mx-record

I have changed the MX records for my domain to host my emails on Gmail. But the problem is that, I'm not able to receive any emails from Hotmail.

Here's the SPF record as taken from [kitterman tool](http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html):

```
The TXT records found for your domain are:
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

And this is a screenshot for my MX records values from MXToolBox.com:
[image]

Kindly note that I can send emails to any provider (including Hotmail) and can receive emails from any provider just NOT Hotmail.

Anyone has any idea why that could be?

Comment: Can you please provide your domain name have a look.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I am experiencing the same issue here

Comment: No. Still no solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DNS records seem good.

This behavior might be caused by the Hotmail DNS cache mechanisms, especially if you tried to send an email from hotmail to that particular domain before your new MX records were active.

Better try sending another email from Hotmail after 24 hours and I think your issue would be gone.

Meanwhile in about 24 hours after sending your unsuccessful Hotmail messages you should have reports back to your Hotmail account explaining why these messages failed receiving the destination.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it's already been more than 24 hours since my DNS changed. and this is the error email sending failure I receive from Hotmail `This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification. Delivery to the following recipients failed.` with no explanation at all.

Comment: Can you please paste the source of this email to pastebin for example so I can look at it?

Comment: It's `This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification. Delivery to the following recipients failed. info@DOMAIN.COM` that's all.

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-osend/how-do-i-interpret-the-delivery-failure-message/2f1bf9c0-8b03-4f8f-aacc-5f6ba60a73f3 Please poste message SOURCE, that contains header part, along with the "Diagnostic-Code".

Comment: how to get the message source?

Comment: http://email.about.com/od/windowslivehotmailtips/qt/How_to_See_Full_Email_Headers_in_Windows_Live_Hotmail.htm

Comment: `Final-Recipient: rfc822;info@ladien.com.sa
Action: failed
Status: 5.5.0
Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client. 
550-dub0-omc4-s14.dub0.hotmail.com [157.55.2.89]:1972 is not permitted to relay
550 through this server without authentication.`

Comment: This seems to be Hotmail issue, 100% similar to that: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-osend/email-bounce-backs-when-sending-to-google-apps/878ba8ab-b6fe-426d-9fec-8d86269e7f19 Better start a new topic similar to that one in the Microsoft's forum so hopefully their support would see it and take care for you as they did for the other guy.